# Google Maps Marker blocks page scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps markers to show some locations with custom icons. Sometimes there are a lot and on mobile the markers take up a good portion of the screen.

[image]

I set google maps to `gestureHandling: 'cooperative',` so the page can be scrolled while the map is on screen. When the user starts scrolling on a marker, the "Use two fingers to move the map" info appears but the page does not scroll. Start dragging anywhere on the map, the page scrolls just like intended.

This behaviour can also be observed on the Marker API Docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) in mobile mode (touch).

Is there a way to unlock page scrolling when the user starts on a marker?

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or a feature... Might be worth reporting in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) and you should find out.

Comment: I did https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180643340

Answer (score 3):

I found that adding a `touchstart` listener to all marker `<img` tags which stops propagation will block google's event and thus allow page scrolling.

I've had luck with the following code, but it is worth noting that:

- `tilesloaded` is not strictly when markers are loaded so its a bit of a race condition. If you can find a better event then let me know.
- The selector is a bit messy, it captures all of my marker images but I'd be happier if it was more intentionally specific.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "tilesloaded", () => document.querySelectorAll(`.gm-style div[role='button'] img[draggable='false']`).forEach(x => x.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => { e.stopImmediatePropagation() })));
```

I've also upvoted the issue but I'm not holding my breath.